# event received from child is never updated

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am able to send an event from my child, but the values never change. This is because I had to initialize my object in my parent.

in parent

```
const courses: Ref<undefined|Course[]> = ref()

const f = ref<IFilter>({
    advanced: false,
    all: true,
    docker: false,
    gcp: false,
    go: false,
});

api.getAll(1,6, f.value).then(c => courses.value = c)

function checkit() {
    console.log("fired " + f.value.go)
    api.getAll(1,6, f.value).then(c => courses.value = c)
}

<template>
    <div v-if="!courses">Loading courses...</div>
    <div v-else>
        <div class="flex grid-cols-2 justify-start">
            <div class="">
                <Filter :filter="f" @filter-change="checkit"/>
            </div>
</template>
```

then in my child I have

```
const filter = ref<IFilter>({
   advanced: false,
   all: true,
   docker: false,
   gcp: false,
   go: false,
});


const emit = defineEmits(['filterChange'])

let updateFilter = () => {
    console.log("value in filter " + filter.value.go)
    emit('filterChange', filter.value);
}
```

template snippet

```
<template>
                    <div class="flex items-start">
                        <div class="flex items-center h-5">
                            <input id="gcp" name="gcp" type="checkbox" v-model="filter.gcp" v-on:change="updateFilter"
                                   class="focus:ring-indigo-500 h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 border-gray-300 rounded">
                        </div>
                        <div class="ml-3 text-sm">
                            <label for="gcp" class="font-medium text-gray-200">GCP</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</template>
```

The event in the child is logging a change but in the parent it is statically set to the values which initialized it. How do I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event includes the updated filter data, you can use that to update the filter values in the parent:

```
function checkit(changedFilter:IFilter) { // pass in child filter value
  f.value = changedFilter  // assign the child filter values to local filter
  ...
}
```

That should be all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `reactive()` instead of `ref()` , to manage the state of an object.
try it:

```
const f = reactive<IFilter>({
    advanced: false,
    all: true,
    docker: false,
    gcp: false,
    go: false,
});
```

Comment: it has no effect.